# $\int_0^r \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{3}{2}} dy$

Tags: calculus

I have an idea that this needs to be done using trig-substitution, since the denominator has a sum of squares, but I honestly don't know how to proceed. Even when I use WolframAlpha to try and solve it I get no results. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get no results in Wolfram Alpha? Strange, the primitive function is $\frac{y}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Comment: I suspect Wolfram Alpha is reluctant to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here because it doesn't know whether there is a singularity ($x^2 + y^2 = 0$) in the interval $[0,r]$.  Of course for real $x$ and $r$ this only happens if $x=0$, but computer algebra systems generally work over the complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Set $y=x\sinh(q)$

This yields

$$
x^{-2}\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}(r/x)}\frac{1}{\cosh^2(q)}dq=x^{-2}\tanh(q)|_0^{\sinh^{-1}(r/x)}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't the right endpoint be $\text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)$? The integral is in $dq$, I bet.

Comment: Sure @Jack D'Aurizo, forgot the $^{-1}
$. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=\arctan y/x\implies y=x\tan u$

$\cos u=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+(y/x)^2}}=\dfrac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

$x^2+y^2=x^2\sec^2u$ and $dy=x\sec^2u\ du$

$$\int\dfrac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}=\int\dfrac{x\sec^2u\ du}{x^3\sec^3u}=\dfrac{\sin u}{x^2}+K$$